# Directed graph won't connect to other nodes

Tags: java

I feel like an idiot because I'm sure this is something simple, but I'm still in school and still learning, so I'm sure I'll deserve the razzing I'll get for asking... I'm working on a project to create a directed unweighted graph. The graph needs to be formed in adjacency list representation which I've done; however, I've hit a snag. The code for adding a vertex (`Node`), edge, and creating the list itself is below:

```
public class Node<T> {
    T data;
    protected boolean marked = false;
    protected boolean cycle = false;
    protected ArrayList<Node<T>> edges = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
        
    Node(T data){
        this.data = data;
    }
    
    public void addEdges(Node<T> edgy) {
        edges.add(edgy);
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return (String) data;
    }
    
}


DirectedGraph<String> graph = new DirectedGraph<String>();

for(String currLine: fileLines) {
    //TODO create nodes
    String[] classes = currLine.split(" ");
    Node<String> headliner = null;
    for(String currClass : classes) {
        Node<String> currNode = new Node<String>(currClass);                    
        if (headliner == null) {
            graph.addVertex(currNode);
            headliner = currNode;
        }
        else {
            graph.addEdge(headliner, currNode);
        }
    }
}
```

The graph shows up in debugger fine, except that the internal nodes (The ArrayList of nodes in the Nodes class) don't have any pointers to the other vertices of the same name, so the graph doesn't connect there. I'm at a loss and didn't know where else to ask...

Edit: Since many were asking for the DirectedGraph class

```
public class DirectedGraph<T>{
    Heirarchy<T> heir = new Heirarchy<T>();
    ArrayList<Node<T>> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    Node<T> root;
    Node<T> parent;
    
    public DirectedGraph() {
        
    }
    
    public void addVertex(Node<T> node) {
        for (Node<T> curr : nodes) {
            if (curr.data.equals(node)) {
                return;
            }
        }
        nodes.add(node);
    }
    
    public void addEdge(Node<T> source, Node<T> dest) {
        source.addEdges(dest);
    }
    
    
    public void performAction(DFSActionsInterface<T> action) {
        if (!nodes.isEmpty()) {
            performAction(action, nodes.get(0));
        }
    }
//   depth_first_search(vertex s)
    
    public void DFS() {
        setFalse();
        root = nodes.get(0);
        while(!nodes.isEmpty()) {
            for (Node<T> curr : nodes) {
                if (!curr.marked) {
                    DFS(curr);
                    visited(curr);
                }
            }
        }
        heir.processVertex(root);
    }
    public void DFS(Node<T> node) {
        while(!node.edges.isEmpty()) {
            for (Node<T> vertex: node.edges) {
                if(!vertex.marked) {
                    for(Node<T> source: nodes) {
                        if (source.edges.contains(vertex) || vertex.edges.contains(source)) {
                            vertex.cycle = true;
                            return;
                        }
                        vertex.marked = true;

                    }
                } return;
            }
        }
    }

    
    public void performAction(DFSActionsInterface<T> action, Node<T> curr) {
//       it should first initialize all the vertices to the undiscovered state
        setFalse();
        if(nodes.contains(curr.data)) {
//       if s is discovered
//       perform cycle detected action
            action.cycleDetected(curr);
//       return
            return;
        }
//       perform add vertex action
//       mark s as discovered
        visited(curr);
//       perform descend action
        action.descend(curr);
//       for all adjacent vertices v
//       depth_first_search(v)
        performAction(action, curr.edges.get(0));
//       perform ascend action
        action.ascend(curr);
//       mark s as finished
            
    }
    public void setFalse() {
        for (Node<T> node : nodes) {
            node.marked = false;
            for(Node<T> edge : node.edges) {
                edge.marked = false;
            }
        }
    }
    public void visited(Node<T> node) {
        node.marked = true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the graph described by the debugger (or a relevant bit showing where it isn't meeting your requirements)?

Comment: What is `DirectedGraph` ?

Comment: Without seeing `DirectedGraph` it's hard to say, but you're performing a copy instead of holding pointers. That might have something to do with it.

Comment: I added the DirectedGraph

Comment: OT: if they are stupid problems or tricky ones they still remains problems, and problems have to be resolved. Don't be afraid of asking or understimate the problems you face. You're on the way of becoming a good problem solver if you want to learn.

Comment: You’re not wrong Marte, but I’ve been hurt before…

Comment: In `addVertex()`, this line `if (curr.data.equals(node)) {` should probably be `if (curr.data.equals(node.data)) {` so that you are comparing the DATA from both nodes. As written, you're comparing data to node, apples to oranges. But the method seems suspect as you're only searching the "root" nodes and never look at the nodes within the current code to see if the node you're looking for might be in there. It would help if we could see the input(s) and the expected output(s)/graph as well...